# Duplicate symbol "buf_position" in C Language code

Tags: c, microcontroller

In this program I am getting error that Duplicate symbol "_buf_position" in C..\async.obj
I have declared buf_position as a global variable I don't know what wrong with this code, Can someone please have a look.

//async.h file

```
extern uint8_t buffer[10];
extern uint32_t buf_position = 0;
extern uint8_t local_buff[10];
extern uint32_t retVal;
```

//async.c file

```
#include "async.h"
void Transmit_Data(void)
{ 
.............
...........
}

void Excep_SCI0_RXI0(void)//This is a recive interrupt,when some data is available on serialport
{

  buffer[buf_position++]= SCI0.RDR;
}
```

// main.c

```
#include "async.h"

void main(void)
{
    while(buffer[buf_position-1]=='\r')
    {
        memcpy(local_buff,buffer,buf_position-1);
        Display_LCD(LCD_LINE1, local_buff);
        Transmit_Data(); 
        buf_position = 0;
        //memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're defining `buf_position` in every file that includes `async.h`. Remove the initialization in `async.h`:

```
extern uint32_t buf_position;
```

and now you're only *declaring* it.

In `async.c`, add the initialization:

```
#include "async.h"

uint32_t buf_position = 0;
uint8_t buffer[10];
uint8_t local_buff[10];
uint32_t retVal;
```